# kotlin Converts bytearray to String data crash

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Converts bytearray data received through communication into String.

If the byte array is long (ex 355), the end is truncated.

Same goes for utf-8, utf-16 etc.

```
fun getString(content:ByteArray, length: Int): String? {
    var str: String? = null

    try {
        str = String(content, 0, length, Charset.forName("euc-kr"))
        i("Test::getString str : " + str)
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        i("Test::getString ERR ")
        error("Charset exception", DlgAprList::class.java)
    }
    return str
}
```

Occurs when it exceeds 355 bytes, if you look at the image of the attached link, it was 389 bytes and you can see that truncation occurred.

[image]

In other functions, use the getString function like this.

```
var str : String? = getString(data, data.size)
var info: Array<String> = str!!.split(";").toTypedArray()
for (i in 0 until info.size - 1) {
                var temp = info[i].split("-".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                var name = temp[0]
                var desc = temp[1]
                var final = name +"-"+ desc
                var finalresult : DlgAprInfo = DlgAprInfo(name,desc)
                i("Test::parseAndReplace temp size : " + info.size + " temp " + i +" : " + finalresult.name + "-"+ finalresult.desc)
                //listnew.add(final)
                list.add(finalresult) // testver
            }
```

I've attached the code from the first receiving point

```
_networkReader = BufferedInputStream(BufferedInputStream(_socket!!.getInputStream()))
                                        var bytesRead = _networkReader!!.read(buffer, 0, Companion.BUFFER_LEN)
if (bytesRead >= 0) {
   if (!_connect) NotifyConnect()
    var command = buffer[4]
    var content: ByteArray? = null
    var length : Int = 0
    var index = 0
    while (index + 3 < bytesRead) {
       var contentlength: Int = ((buffer[index] and 0xff.toByte()).toInt() shl 24) + ((buffer[index + 1] and 0xff.toByte()).toInt() shl 16) + ((buffer[index + 2] and 0xff.toByte()).toInt() shl 8) + ((buffer[index + 3] and 0xff.toByte()).toInt() shl 0)
      var cmd = buffer[index + 4]
      if (bytesRead > Companion.COMMAND_LEN) {
         content = ByteArray(bytesRead - index - Companion.COMMAND_LEN - 4)
         length = content.size
         System.arraycopy(buffer, index + 5, content, 0, contentlength)
     }
  processPacket(cmd, content, contentlength)
  }
}
```

processPacket Function

```
private fun processPacket(command: Byte, content: ByteArray?, length: Int) {
            try {
                if (content != null) {
                    LogUtil.i("StandElin 1-1 " + "Command 0x" + Integer.toHexString(command.toInt()) + " "
                            + String(content, 0, length, CHARSET))
                } else {
                    LogUtil.i("StandElin 1-2" + "Command 0x" + Integer.toHexString(command.toInt()))
                }
                LogUtil.i("StandElin 2 FinalCommand : 0x" + Integer.toHexString(command.toInt()))
                var message: Message? = null
                var parsed: Any? = null

DlgAprList.instance?.parseAndReplace(content)
```

The first code attached to the top is a function included in the DlgAprList class

Comment: You asked this before. In the same words. What happened?

Comment: What is the value of length? It should be content.size and there would be no need to pass it as separate parameter into your first method.

Comment: Right . value of length  is contet.size. 
Added a bit of source code for the contents of other functions that use get string.

Comment: @blackapps There was no progress and I posted a new article because I wanted to fix this problem.

Comment: Well post the code for an initialized byte array and show how you call that function. Also tell what it is that is in the byte array as even that you did not tell and you cannot convert all byte values to a string.

Comment: You can remove that last code block as it looks irrelevant what you do with the obtained string.

Comment: Could you paste some example data when it crashes? (i means values of content you pass into the function).

Comment: @Cililing An example of a data crash attached an image as a link.

Comment: @blackapps catch code blocks?

Comment: Would be easier if you pasted the data, not an image. How am I supposed to copy them? :(

Comment: @Cililing  Are you talking about the data I acquire?

Comment: @blackapps The code was attached from the first data reception part.

Comment: As I understand the unexpected error occurs in `getString` method. I think about pair of values - input and expected result (like `input = [0, 1, 4, 1, 9...]`, `expected =  "abc"`). It would be much easier to find out a proper solution with some test cases.

Comment: `attached the code from the first receiving point`. Nobody asked for that. We cannot test that. We asked something different. Well read the comments...

Answer (score 0):

I created a repo that you can run your use-cases against with tests: [GitHub](https://github.com/ChameleonTartu/so-answers/tree/main/so-65712797)

There are several possible issues:

- Can `Log.i` cause any troubles?
- Check the initial encoding you encode with:

```
val str = "My long string"
val byteArray = str.toByteArray(Charset.forName("utf-8"))
```

- Check the encoding you decode with. In your code, I see that `euc-kr` encoding is hard-coded. It means that if you encoded with utf-8 and decode with a different one, the code will fail.

Comment: @drogba As I am a back-end developer, I created a back-end service. If you can publish a minimal Android version that reproduces your issue, I can debug it.